# Design patterns for network protocols?

Tags: java, design-patterns, networking, protocols

So I'm building a fairly simple file transfer server/client but having a hard time to figure out a good design for processing different commands and states within the protocol..

Say that you have 3 different commands `upload`, `remove`, `download`, you could use 3 different if-statements and keep track of states with additional if-statements, but that wont scale and will be *impossible* to maintain..

The Chain Of Responsibility design pattern could be used for sequential stuff such as encryption and compression, but it wont take care of the logic for commands.

I know that this is a quite broad question, but does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You can always use a `Map<String, Command>` where keys are command names and values are implementations of an interface for executing these commands. That is one solution amongst many

Answer (score 1):

The following may be helpful:

To provide different implementations for the same operation based on some conditions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

To maintain state of the communication (e.g. the current protocol command): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

For security/compression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern or Chain-of-responsibility