# What's a good design pattern to implement a network protocol (XML)?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, design-patterns

I want to implement a network protocol. To obtain a maintainable design I am looking for fitting patterns.

The protocol is based on XML and should be read with java. To simplify the discussion here I assume the example grammar:

```
<User>
  <GroupList>
    <Group>group1</Group>
    <Group>group2</Group>
  </GroupList>
</User>
```

Short question:
What is a good design pattern to parse such thing?

Long version:
I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450408/how-to-implement-a-network-protocol) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801110/design-patterns-for-network-protocols) where different patterns (mostly state pattern) are proposed.

My actual (but lacking) solution is the folowing:
I create for each possible entry in the XML a class to contain the data and a parser. Thus I have `User`, `User.Parser`, ... as classes.
Further there is a `ParserSelector` that has a `Map<String,AbstractParser>` in which all possible subentries get registered.
For each parser a `ParserSelector` gets instantiated and set up.
For example the `ParserSelector` of the `GroupList.Parser` has one entry: The mapping from the string `"Group"` to an instance of `Group.Parser`.
If I did not use the `ParserSleector` class, I would have to write this block of code into every single parser.

The problem is now how to get the read data to the superobjects.
The `Group.Parser` would create a `Group` object with content `group1`.
This object must now be registered in the `GroupList` object.
I have read of using Visitor or Observer patterns but do not understand how they might fit here.

I give some pseudo code below to see the problem.
You see, that I have to check via `instanceof` for the type as statically there is the type information not available.

I thought this should be possible to solve using polymorphism in java in a cleaner (more maintainable) way.
I always face then the problem that java does only do dynamic binding on overriding.
Thus I cannot add a parameter to the `XMLParser.parse(...)` method to allow of "remote updating" as in a visitor/observer like approach.

Side remark: The real grammar is "deep" that is, it is such that there are quite many XML entries (here only three: `User`, `GroupList` and `Group`) while most of them might contain only very few different subentries (`User` and `GroupList` may only contain one subentry here, while `Group` itself contains only text).

Here comes some lines of pseude java code to explain the problem:

```
class User extends AbstractObject {
    static class Parser implements XMLParser {

        ParserSelector ps = ...; // Initialize with GroupList.Parser

        void parse(XMLStreamReader xsr){
            XMLParser p = ps.getParser(...); // The corresponding parser.
            // We know only that it is XMLParser statically.

            p.parse(...);

            if(p instanceof GroupList.Parser){
                // Set the group list in the User class
            }
        }
    }
}

class GroupList extends AbstractObject{...}
class Group extends AbstractObject{...}

class ParserSelector{
    Map<String,XMLParser> = new Map<>();
    void registerParser(...){...} // Registers a possible parser for subentries

    XMLParser getParser(String elementName){
        return map.get(elementName); // Returns the parser registered with the given name
    }
}

interface XMLParser {
    void parse(XMLStreamReader xsr);
}

abstract class AbstractObject{}
```

Comment: http://www.eaipatterns.com/EnvelopeWrapper.html

Comment: I'd use the "use an existing XML -> POJO library" pattern.

Comment: You are reinventing a lot of wheels.  First order of business is to learn the existing Java classes for reading and manipulating XML, `javax.xml.*`, `org.xml.sax.*`, `org.w3c.dom.*` to avoid rewriting versions of them.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have no intention to rewirite them. Instead I wand to parse using the STax classes (not SAX) to bring the relevant data to a pure java object structure. Later (in the rest of the program code) this data will be delt with. I do not want to have to handle these things in the other control logic. Think of it as an abstraction layer.

Comment: @DaveNewton The reason I wanted to code it myself was to allow different protocol versions (network application!). I wanted to add some attribute to the xml root node to qualify the protocol version. On modifications I could easyly use classes from a separate package with the old classes. On using a linbary I have the problem that I cannot change the protocol definition "on the fly". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish this question:

I ended up with `JAXB`. In fact I was not aware of the fact that it allows to easily create a XML Schema from java source code (using annotations).

Thus I just have to write the code with classical java objects which are used for transfer. Then the API handles the conversion to and from XML quite well.